# "Automation" versus "automatization"

Tags: word-usage, synonyms, programming, technical

I would like to characterize the action of making a process go automatically instead of doing it manually. The context is computer programming. A programmer may type in 10 pieces of code with only a small item differing across them; or she may create a loop where a single piece is run 10 times with a slight variation; the end result is the same in both cases.

Should I use the words "automate" and "automation", or "automatize" and "automatization" (or yet something else)?

Comment: The common and idiomatic term is *automate*. I don't believe I've seen *automatize* actually used in the wild.

Comment: Merriam Webster defines [*automatize*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/automatize) as " to make (an action) reflexive." It appears you want [*automate*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/automate) " to run or operate (something, such as a factory or system) by using machines, computers, etc., instead of people to do the work."

Comment: disagreeing with Dan, automatization is a totally valid and useful word.  i'd have to think about it but it means, talking about a business, "doing a lot of automating of different systems".  agreeing with Dan, I think simply "automate" is right here

Comment: Just throwing my hat in the ring a few years later. I hear people using "automize"/"automizing"/"automization" often. Granted, English is a sencond language here, but I found it interesting. It is not listed as a word at Meriam Webster, but some other sites list it as a valid replacement for "automate"/"automating"/"automation"

Comment: @Eldamir, interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [wikidiff](http://www.wikidiff.com/automatization/automation):

> Automatization is a related term of automation. As nouns the
>   difference between automation and automatization is that **automation** is
>   the act or process of converting the controlling of a machine or
>   device to a more automatic system, such as computer or electronic
>   controls while **automatization** is a process of making an action of a
>   higher animal reflexive.

On the other hand, the free dictionary offers a definition for the verb *[to automatize](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/automatize)* (= To make automatic) which makes it identical to the verb *[to automate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/automate)* (= To convert to automatic operation;  To control or operate by automation).

In my opinion, although *to automatize* (or *to automatise*) is a valid word, *to automate* (and the noun automation) is far more frequently used according to [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=automate%2Cautomatize%2C%20automatise&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cautomate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cautomatize%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cautomatise%3B%2Cc0).